# sending transactional sms from twilio

Tags: twilio, sms-gateway

I am working on a doctor-patient app **TrustCircle**. Where I need to send sms as transactional not promotional but by default all the sms in India are being sent as promotional by twilio. Is there any way I can send transactional sms through twilio.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in

By default, Twilio sends messages to India as promotional messages. If you are sending transactional content, we highly recommend you register your Sender ID. Sending transactional traffic with a registered Sender ID bypasses the DND database and time restriction. Create a subaccount and split out your transactional SMS traffic to ensure you are complian

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-Started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS